# Where can I edit the Copyright of my Python Bundle created with py2app?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, py2app

I use py2app for the creation of stand alone apps from my python scripts. I have Tkinter used in the script called "MyApp" but I wonder where I can edit the copyright of my app? When I go to "About MyApp" from menu bar which was created by py2app, I see the Tkinter copyright.

So, what do I need to do to get my own name for my own app in py2app here?

Wishes,
Mike

[image: macOS: Go "MyApp"->About you get this.]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Calculate something")
root.config(background="#FFFFFF")


leftFrame = Frame(root, width=200, height=400)
leftFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=3)

leftLabel1 = Label(leftFrame, text="This app helps to calculate")
leftLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=3)


rightFrame = Frame(root, width=200, height=400)
rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

rightLabel1 = Label(rightFrame, text="1st number:")
rightLabel1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

rightLabel2 = Label(rightFrame, text="2nd number")
rightLabel2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

rightLabel3 = Label(rightFrame, text="you get")
rightLabel3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=25)

num1_var = DoubleVar()
num2_var = DoubleVar()

# entrys
num1_ent = Entry(rightFrame, width=30, textvariable=num1_var)
num1_ent.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=3)

num2_ent = Entry(rightFrame, width=30, textvariable=num2_var)
num2_ent.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=3)

def calc():
    num1 = num1_var.get()
    num2 = num2_var.get()

    if num1 == num2:
        messagebox.showerror(titel = "Error", message = "Different numbers are needed", icon = "error")
    elif num1 < num2:
        rightLabel4 = Label(rightFrame, width=30, text=((num2 - num1)-1))
        rightLabel4.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=25)
    elif num1 > num2:
        rightLabel4 = Label(rightFrame, width=30, text=((num2 - num1)-5))
        rightLabel4.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=25)

buttonFrame = Frame(rightFrame)
buttonFrame.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)
B1 = Button(rightFrame, text="Do it", bg="#FF0000", width=15, command=calc)
B1.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=50, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter copyright? Can you include a screenshot or something?

Comment: I added a pic, now. I get this, when I go to "My App" -> "About" in the menubar, where all macOS apps do have this about button. I will distribute "My App" to others, so I would like to have my copyright in "My App". How is it possible?

Comment: Ive never noticed this on my app, ive created. I can confirm `exe` does not have something like this, or i havent noticed something like this YET

Comment: ok, thanks. I still would like to edit it. Helping hand available?

Comment: Include some code? So we can see what is going on? Are you making a `Menu`?

Comment: OK, here is the code. I'm not using a menu or something. just entry widget and message box

Comment: Ive copied this thing exactly on and tried it, but still i dont have a menu, maybe this is just the problem with macOS apps

Comment: Anyway, take a look at these - [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441279/how-to-replace-the-about-tkinter-menu-in-python-on-osx), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009909/change-title-of-tkinter-application-in-os-x-menu-bar)